# Calling Django child model method from parent requires InheritanceManager?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Post` class for my Django app that has several subclasses `TextPost`, `AudioPost`, etc, each with their own `render_html()` method.

```
class Post(models.Model): 
   author = models.ForeinKey(User,...)
   title = models.CharField(...)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField(...)
   ...
   def render_html(self): 
       return "rendered title, author date"

class AudioPost(Post):
   audioFile = FileField(...)
   def render_html(self):
      return "Correct audio html"
...
```

each of these child models has an `ModelForm` with rules for uploading, validation, and saving.

In a home page view, I'd like to take all posts, arrange them by date, and render them. To me this should be as simple as

```
## in view
context = { 'posts' : Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5] }
```

and

```
## in template
{{ post.render_html() | safe }}
```

I remember things working this way for abstract classes in Java. But when I do it this way in Python, the `render_html` method gets called as if they are each members of the parent class. I've looked up how Django does multi-table inheritence, it seems like I either need to check the generated `OneToOneFields` one by one until I've found one that doesn't raise an exception, or use the `InheritanceManager` utility manager. Is one of those two ways the best way to do this or should I do something else?

Comment: Because they *are* members of their parent class. If you query for Posts, then you get Posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another method for your problem which you can use to get all the subclasses of the base class. It will be a bit of handy as you don't need to get query set for every child class manually

```
querysets_child = [child_cls.objects.all() for child_cls in vars()['BaseClass'].__subclasses__()]
```

The method you refer to which works on java but I don't think it can work here. Either you use child classes manually or get all child classes with subclass function mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via the following method inside `Post`, which allows me to do

```
{{ post.get_subclass().render_html() }}
```

inside the template. Assuming 4 subclasses, `AudioPost`, `VideoPost`, `TextPost`, and `RichTextPost`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    ...
    def get_subclass(self):
        try:
            textpost = self.textpost
            return textpost
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        try:
            audiopost = self.audiopost
            return audiopost
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        try:
            videopost = self.videopost
            return videopost
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        try:
            richtextpost = self.richtextpost
            return richtextpost
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        raise ObjectDoesNotExist
```